# Load balancing and scaling in Kinesis Client library (KCL) based application

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-kcl

I am using [amazon-kinesis-connectors](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-connectors) to build a kinesis client side application. I am figuring out few things about it.

How KCL ensures load balancing and scaling. for example i have a stream with one shard and a lot of records/events are put for 15 mintues in whole day or for certain time. So how it will take care of such sudden traffic and load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For load balancing, you need multiple shards. Kinesis attempts to balance the number of shards each worker takes on - if you only have one shard, you won't get any benefit from more than one worker.  See [my related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47124729/836214) here for a bit more information on how Kinesis load balancing works.

As for scaling - each shard has a limit to maximum amount of traffic it can take - from the [kinesis limitation docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/service-sizes-and-limits.html):

> Each shard can support up to 1,000 records per second for writes, up to a maximum total data write rate of 1 MB per second

The way you scale up with kinesis is add more shards - more shards == more throughput.  You can either have these shards pre-created, or you can add them as your traffic increases.